# Unable to probe for mimetype from filename

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am reading in a file from azure. And the mimetype is `video/mp4` which is in the `response.headers["content-type"]`. I can't find how to add mimetypes to files because I am getting the following error

> Unable to probe mimetype from filename

```
axios({
  method: "get",
  url: "https://stemuli.blob.core.windows.net/stemuli/mentor-lesson-video-c20665e2-b17c-4f22-9ef8-f6cd62b113dd.mp4",
  responseType: "stream"
}).then(function (response) {
  const videoType = response.headers["content-type"].split("/")[1];

  const file = fs.createWriteStream(
    `./cache/thumbnails/${tempFileName + "."}${videoType}`
  );
  response.data.pipe(file);

  thumbsupply
    .generateThumbnail(`./cache/thumbnails/${tempFileName}`)
    .then(thumb => res.json(thumb))
    .catch(err => {
      res.json({
        Error: "Error creating thumbnail for video"
      });
      console.log(err);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're receiving is coming from the thumbsupply package on the line:

```js
 thumbsupply
    .generateThumbnail(`./cache/thumbnails/${tempFileName}`)
```

You can [see the error message in their code](https://github.com/RyanAfrish7/thumbsupply/blob/faca8bf1ccadca39696c6ea2b5b8a70104647b56/index.js#L40):

```js
    _fetchThumbnailSupplier(file, options) {
        const mime = options.mimetype || mimetypes.lookup(file);
        let Supplier;

        if (!mime) {
            throw new E.UnknownFiletypeError(file, undefined, "Unable to probe mimetype from filename");
        }
```

So you can correct your code by simply passing in the mimetype option:

```js
  thumbsupply
    .generateThumbnail(`./cache/thumbnails/${tempFileName}`,
        { mimetype: response.headers["content-type"] } )
```

Comment: Thanks compiler =]. Thank you for going into depth for this.